# Google Maps API - location finder

Tags: google-api, geolocation, maps, zipcode, html4

We are a site that would like to show the different areas on a map where recycling bins that are associated with our company are located based on your zip code. since we cant host it on our html4 site i wanted to use maybe an external link?

let me know if anyone can help explain this to me :) or if there is a better way to do this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to create a shareable map as a reference for the locations of recycling bins. I would recommend using Google Maps.

At https://www.google.com/maps/d/, you can create your own maps. There are multiple ways to add your data to the map. They let you draw, drop pins, or upload spreadsheet data. You can read more about adding your data at their [help page](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024925?visit_id=1-636143953405898080-2583072298&p=lite_addplaces&rd=1).

Once you've created a map, you can embed it on your website or simply add the link to your page.